# SQL Server Incorrect Syntax error

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

Thank for your help and reading, I have the below query and I don't understand why this error message occurs:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Price'

I am able to query this data column (Wholesale Price) in a standalone query. I'm using SQL Server 2005 Management Studio .

```
SELECT 
    ILE.[Location Code],
    ILE.SUM(Quantity) AS "Transfer Qty",
    PP.SUM(Wholesale Price) AS "Transfer Cost (HK)"
FROM 
    [DB].[dbo].[Company$Item Ledger Entry] ILE
INNER JOIN 
    [DB].[dbo].[Company$Purchase Price] PP ON ILE.[Item No_] = PP.[Item No_] 
                                           AND ILE.[Variant Code] = PP.[Variant Code]
WHERE
    ILE.[Entry Type] = '4' 
    AND ILE.[Location Code] NOT LIKE '%STAFF%' 
    AND ILE.[Location Code] NOT LIKE 'WHSPACKAGE' 
    AND ILE.[Location Code] NOT LIKE 'WHS'
GROUP BY
    ILE.[Location Code], ILE.[Quantity], PP.[Wholesale Price]
ORDER BY 
    [Location Code]
```

Thanks!

Regards,
Patrick

Comment: You are missing square braces around `Wholesale Price`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SQL, you have to escape names that contain special characters -- and spaces are special characters.  Because reading and writing code that has lots of square braces is cumbersome, the general advice is to avoid using such names.

In your case, you are missing the square braces:

```
SELECT ILE.[Location Code], ILE.Sum(Quantity) as "Transfer Qty",
       Sum(PP.[Wholesale Price]) as "Transfer Cost (HK)"
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Company$Item Ledger Entry] ILE INNER JOIN
     [DB].[dbo].[Company$Purchase Price] PP
     ON ILE.[Item No_] = PP.[Item No_] AND
        ILE.[Variant Code] = PP.[Variant Code]
Where ILE.[Entry Type] = '4' AND
      ILE.[Location Code] NOT LIKE '%STAFF%' AND
      ILE.[Location Code] NOT LIKE 'WHSPACKAGE' AND
      ILE.[Location Code] NOT LIKE 'WHS'
Group by ILE.[Location Code], ILE.[Quantity]
Order by [Location Code];
```

In addition:

- `PP.SUM()` doesn't make sense.  The table alias goes with the column name.
- Putting the wholesale price in the `GROUP BY` doesn't make sense.  You want to aggregate the value, so it usually wouldn't go there.

Answer (score 0):

Check this select statement for your error

```
SELECT 
    ILE.[Location Code],
    ILE.SUM(Quantity) AS "Transfer Qty",
    PP.SUM([Wholesale Price]) AS "Transfer Cost (HK)"--Error line
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much! Gordon!

Both SUM statement should be wording this format, 
     Sum(ILE.[Quantity] and Sum(PP.[Wholesale Price])

```
    SELECT ILE.[Location Code], Sum(ILE.[Quantity]) as "Transfer Qty",
           Sum(PP.[Wholesale Price]) as "Transfer Cost (HK)"
      FROM [Dummy-28-Oct-2016].[dbo].[TEST ENV$Item Ledger Entry] ILE       
INNER JOIN [Dummy-28-Oct-2016].[dbo].[TEST ENV$Purchase Price] PP
        ON ILE.[Item No_] = PP.[Item No_] 
       AND ILE.[Variant Code] = PP.[Variant Code]
     Where ILE.[Entry Type] = '4' 
       AND ILE.[Location Code] NOT LIKE '%STAFF%' 
       AND ILE.[Location Code] NOT LIKE 'WHSPACKAGE' 
       AND ILE.[Location Code] NOT LIKE 'WHS'
  Group by ILE.[Location Code], ILE.[Quantity]
  Order by [Location Code];
```